# Weakly typed language type conversion of meaning where, why use. For example JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Weakly typed language type conversion is not necessary, can directly use it, why type conversion.

Comment: It's clear English isn't easy for you but as it is, the question isn't understandable at all. Please try to extend it so that we can find out what you want.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think s/he meant to ask "Because Javascript is a weakly typed language, type conversion is not necessary. Why do we have type conversion, then?" [I am translating, not advocating OPs question or the assumptions within]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is weakly typed.

That means that variables don't have a fixed type.

But that doesn't mean values aren't typed : values in javascript all have a type, which may be Number, String, Object (including functions), etc. (see complete list of types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)).

So when you want to make operations that aren't natural for a specific value type (for example interpreting a string as a boolean), a conversion is needed.